# Is there a way to add documentation for Python in eclipse.

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, documentation

I want to see the source code of inbuilt functions. Like for example to add Java docs we use the javafx-src and src zip files inside jdk_1.8.031 folder.

Is there any file which does the same thing in Python. How can we add it in Eclipse?

thanks in advance for you answers

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not available but it is available documentation in :

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial

and some tutorial that might help you

https://developers.google.com/edu/python/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/

Thank you,

Comment: I was able to get it, but not for all the functions. I added the lib folder in python installation folder in C drive, to the Python interpreter in PyDev Library menu

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand